# Empty lists as outputs while scraping with scrapy the html elements

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Am trying to get data from this [website](https://www.viennaairport.com/passagiere/ankunft__abflug/abflueg) , but am getting empty lists with scrapy. I used [selector gadget](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb?hl=en) ,to get the class names of the elements. So I checked the `robots.txt` file of the website and the link am accessing was prohibited.

Then, I used `User-Agent` to bypass the restrictions, but still am wondering why am getting empty lists when I extract the elements.

Below is my `Spider` class :

```
class FlightDestinationSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'flights_destinations'
    start_urls = [
        "https:/xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # flights = HuxyscraperItem()

        # div_flight_table = response.css('div.detail-table__row')
        time1 = response.css('.fdabf-td2').css('::text').extract()
        flight = response.css('.fdabf-td3::text').extract()

        yield {'time': time1, 'flug': flight}
```

Then, in my settings.py I have the following :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for huxyscraper project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'huxyscraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['huxyscraper.spiders']
# NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'huxyscraper.spiders'

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'


# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

PROXY_POOL_ENABLED = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
# CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
# DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
# CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
# CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
# COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
# TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
# DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
# }

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
# SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'huxyscraper.middlewares.HuxyscraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
# }

# DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#     # ...
#     'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.ProxyPoolMiddleware': 610,
#     'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
#     # ...
# }
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
# DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'huxyscraper.middlewares.HuxyscraperDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
# }

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
# EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
# }

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'huxyscraper.pipelines.HuxyscraperPipeline': 300,
}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
# AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
# AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
# AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
# AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
# AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
# HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
# HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
# HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
# HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
# HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

So, when , I run the application, this is the final dictionary I get :

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger/print statement debugging, to check which part of the program may be at fault?

Comment: How do I do that ? @AlexanderCècile

Comment: Well, you could check `time1` and `flight`. Then, `response.css('.fdabf-td2').css('::text')`, `response.css('.fdabf-td2')`, etc. until you find something.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, maybe give me a hint on how to debug , I'll  be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanna crawl [this](https://www.viennaairport.com/jart/prj3/va/data/flights/out.json?dummy=Rc7a6248Xb56e1c9) instead of [this](https://www.viennaairport.com/passagiere/ankunft__abflug/abfluege) because it loads data from [that one](https://www.viennaairport.com/jart/prj3/va/data/flights/out.json?dummy=Rc7a6248Xb56e1c9) so you get empty lists because the data you want does not exists in [that page](https://www.viennaairport.com/passagiere/ankunft__abflug/abfluege).

```py
import scrapy
import json

class FlightDestinationSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'flights_destinations'
    start_urls = [
        "https://xxxxxxxxx.com"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        json_data = json.loads(response.body)
        for data in json_data['monitor']['departure']:
            time1 = data['scheduledatetime']
            flight = data['airline']
            yield {'time': time1, 'flug': flight}
```

Before creating your spider it's beneficial to check website with `scrapy shell` by `view(response)` to find out what you are getting when you `request`.

Comment: Thanks, piron,  for the answer, but maybe my question would be, how did you get to know that, the data is in that `JSON` link? How did you investigate that?


Thanks.

Comment: I think I get it , I need to first check with scrapy shell. That makes sense

Comment: You can find something with inspect tool of browser in network tab.